# How to manage notifications?

Tags: android, notifications

I am developing an Android launcher app. I would like to manage (get, delet launch activity)
notifications. Is there any API to perform these functions? Thanks!

Simon

Answer (score 1):

Notifications are handled by the OS as part of the status bar or system bar. Home screen implementations do not need to worry about them, and there is nothing in the Android SDK to allow home screens to manipulate them.